# Rotating session identifier causing random log-outs, any alternative?

Tags: php, ajax, session

Following the best practices for sessions I have extended `SessionHandler` and regenerate the session ID at random (1 in 10 chance). The sessions work fine and I've started to implement some AJAX calls. However there are some very random cases where the session will be invalidated and the user logged out, I do not know the best and safest solution to this.

Let me walk you through what happens:

Let's say the user "loads more data" and initiates an AJAX call.

```
Browser sends headers including COOKIE, session ID is: klqlk0rldcasbos2f4li1db
```

The session handler validates this, it's fine, *but* we've hit the 1 in 10 chance so we `session_regenerate_id`

```
Server sends back new session ID: sbos2f4li1dbklqlk0rldca
```

During the process of sending data back, the user clicks to another page while the AJAX is still running (small chance, but it can happen).

The new session ID doesn't seem to be stored successfully by the browser. Seemingly if the request is cancelled all data is discarded, including the new session ID. (Not a browser bug, right?).

So then since the user has gone to a new page the client is sending a session ID `klqlk0rldcasbos2f4li1db` NOT the new one `sbos2f4li1dbklqlk0rldca`. Thus invalid session = logout.

I can also reliably reproduce this simply bashing F5 on a page where it doesn't get time to be completely received.

---

**Possible Solutions?**

1. When we `session_regenerate_id` we store the old ID somewhere, add
   some sort of checking.
2. We disable `session_regenerate_id` during any
   AJAX calls. Slight reduction in security and not really a solution.

---

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

I had been using `session_regenerate_id(true)` and setting this back to false (default) solves the issue, but now I'm wondering how good this is at preventing session hijacking if the old session stays on the system? Defeats the point of generating a new ID.

Comment: Is there a 'remember me' cookie for 'auto login' or are you just relying on the 'session' variables?

Comment: There's no "remember me" functionality at the moment. See my update I've found that using `session_regenerate_id(true)` was causing the issue, but now I'm wondering how less secure it would be without that with regards to session hijacking.

Comment: Have you considered using a separate 'ajax user request id' - that would ensure that the session_regenerate_id' processing would not 'mess up' the 'ajax processing' as the 'ajax processing' is no longer tied to to 'session id'?

Comment: Yes that was one of my considerations, I'm just hesitant to use solutions that seem like they're bypassing security elsewhere, but maybe in this use-case there's no reduction in security. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I am not sure why this would reduce security? It allows you to change the session randomly. The extra cost is storing the 'ajax request authorization id' somewhere? Also the 'ajax request id' can be changed on each request if you wish. i.e. it is a one time use.